# Freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04, no Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Hi guys I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm connected with an ethernet cable since I can't connect to the Wi-Fi. I know this might sound like a question that was asked a thousand times but I've tried everything I found online and I can't get it to work.

Among the things I did were:

Reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source;
Disabling the Secure Boot;
Commenting out some blacklist line(I think it was a line with b43 in it);
Also I restarted my laptop infinite times.

I have an SSD with Windows 10 and a HDD partioned in two parts, one of which has Ubuntu. I don't know if this matters.

Any help, please?
Thank you,
Lorenzo

EDIT:
After executing the command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

I get:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2234]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
```

Also the strangest thing just happened. I opened up my laptop and the Wi-Fi was suddenly working, detecting all the networks. Unfortunately right before I clicked on mine to connect, the Wi-Fi was disconnected and they all disappeared.

One more detail:

```
rfkill list
```

Gives as output

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Just ran sudo rfkill list again and I noticed that the Wireless has changed:

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your answers. Here's the link for that information:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23276584/

Comment: Installing Broadcom drivers was wrong. You do not have a Broadcom adapter.

Comment: The issue is with rfkill. You never mentioned that you had an Asus laptop. Probably you need to add a `wapf=4` parameter to `asus_nb_wmi`.

Comment: Why does it matter which computer I have? I didn't think it was important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

and reboot.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Can you explain what it does exactly though? Thank you again.

Comment: This commands created `/etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf` file with `options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4` in it. That sets parameters for Asus platform driver to correctly use rfkill.